# Rails 3.2 ActionMailer - How to get full URL path in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

application.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "server.domain.gov" }
PUBLIC_URL = "http://server/myapp"  
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/myapp'
```

mailer:

```
<%= link_to "View Certificate", certificate_url(@award, :format => "pdf")  %>
```

Clicking the link brings me to:

```
http://server/controller/method
```

It skips the /myapp root after the server.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my routes.rb file to include the app root, which sounds weird to me, but it works.

```
match 'myapp/awards/certificate/:id' => 'awards#certificate', :as => :certificate, :via => :get
```